# "More info" button missing in "About this Mac"

Tags: macos

I have a macbook pro running Yosemite 10.10.5.  When I click on the apple and select "About this Mac", I'm [allegedly supposed to see](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201731) a button "More info", but it's not there.  Is it just me?  How else can I access detailed system information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up **System Information** in `/Applications/Utilities/`.

I don't know why **More Info** isn't showing up, but others have had the issue.

Comment: On my mac I have "System Information" (and no "profiler") and I'm guessing that these are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

There's a System Report... button in the Overview tab.

Answer (score 0):

The page you referenced is for earlier OS. `System Report` should show everything, but if you are looking for something specific it should be accessible through the tabs in `About this Mac`.